# ng-model undefined with empty strings?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am passing user input to a controller function but empty strings do not declare object properties.

```
<form>
  <input type="text" ng-model="data.location" />
  <input type="text" ng-model="data.radius" />
  <button  type="button" ng-click="getSearch(data)">Search</button>
</form>

$scope.getSearch = function(data) {
  console.log(data);
  //undefined
  //...but what if I want {location:'', radius:''}
};
```

Is there a way to force the object properties to be created when passing empty strings on the fly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to initialize data.location and data.radius in your controller to '', at least that way they aren't undefined.

Comment: Sure, but is this the only way? There's no way to force it on the fly?

Comment: @DanKanze no otherwise object will be initialized only when you edit the text box

Comment: ng-init={data: {location: '', radius: ''}" would do the trick, but its same like in controller

Answer (score 3):

You should access it as `$scope.data` and not just `data`.

Also you don't need to pass it as argument to your `getSearch()`. `models` are bound to `$scope` and should be accessed via `$scope`

Comment: Thanks for this that makes more sence then what I was doing.